# CSS browser compatibility issues. Renders fine in Chrome but not in Firefox or IE

Tags: css

I have the following CSS in my project. The CSS rendering perfectly in chrome but fails to render properly on IE and Firefox. The Controls are pushed towards the far right. Any suggestions on what to twick?

```
body {
    background-color:white;
}
.nvbar ul {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    list-style:none;
}
.nvbar li {
    float:left;
    width:11%;
    height:30px;
    line-height:30px;
    text-align:center;
    border-right:6px solid white;
    position:relative;
    background: #0a0a0a;
    /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0a0a0a 0%, #0a0a0a 100%);
    /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #0a0a0a), color-stop(100%, #0a0a0a));
    /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0a0a0a 0%, #0a0a0a 100%);
    /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #0a0a0a 0%, #0a0a0a 100%);
    /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #0a0a0a 0%, #0a0a0a 100%);
    /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0a0a0a 0%, #0a0a0a 100%);
    /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#0a0a0a ', endColorstr='#0a0a0a ', GradientType=0);
    /* IE6-9 */
}
.nvbar li ul {
    position:absolute;
    top:30px;
}
.nvbar li ul li {
    float:none;
    width:180%;
    text-align:left;
    padding-left:4px;
    border-top:2px solid white;
}
.nvbar a {
    /*font-family:Meiryo UI,verdana,san-serif;*/
    font-family: Arial, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color:white;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:bold;
    display:block;
}
.arrow1 {
    width:0px;
    height:0px;
    border-left:7px solid transparent;
    border-right:7px solid transparent;
    border-bottom:7px solid black;
    position:relative;
    right:-70%;
}
.arrow2 {
    width:0px;
    height:0px;
    border-left:7px solid transparent;
    border-right:7px solid transparent;
    border-bottom:7px solid black;
    position:relative;
    right:-70%;
}
.sub1 {
    visibility:hidden;
}
.sub2 {
    visibility:hidden;
}
.srvlist:hover .sub2 {
    visibility:visible;
}
.prjlst:hover .sub1 {
    visibility:visible;
}
.nvbar li:hover {
    background: #eb2139;
    /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #eb2139 0%, #eb2139 100%);
    /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #eb2139), color-stop(100%, #eb2139));
    /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eb2139 0%, #eb2139 100%);
    /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #eb2139 0%, #eb2139 100%);
    /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #eb2139 0%, #eb2139 100%);
    /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #eb2139 0%, #eb2139 100%);
    /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#eb2139', endColorstr='#eb2139', GradientType=0);
    /* IE6-9 */
}
```

The following is the aspx page its supposed to render. Everything starting from the logo downwards are shifted to the right.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebBasedGenerator.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="Layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <style type="text/css">
        .auto-style2 {
            width: 219px;
        }
        .auto-style3 {
            text-align: left;
        }
        .auto-style1 {
            width: 213px;
            height: 61px;
        }
        .auto-style6 {
            width: 145px;
            text-align: left;
        }
        .auto-style7 {
            text-align: left;
            height: 23px;
        }
        .auto-style4 {
            width: 150px;
            text-align: left;
            height: 23px;
        }
        .auto-style5 {}
        .auto-style8 {
            width: 150px;
            text-align: left;
            height: 65px;
        }
        .auto-style9 {
            height: 65px;
        }
        .auto-style12 {
            text-align: left;
            width: 138px;
        }
        .auto-style13 {
            text-align: left;
            height: 23px;
            width: 138px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
         <div class="nvbar">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="WebForm1.aspx">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">    </a></li>
    <li><a href="#">    </a></li>
<%--    <li class="prjlst"><a href="#">Products</a>
    <div class="sub1">
    <ul>
    <div class="arrow1"></div>
    <li><a href="#">Product1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Product2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Product3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Product4</a></li>
    </ul></div>
    </li>--%>
    <li class="srvlist"><a href="#">Services</a>
    <div class="sub2">
    <ul>
    <div class="arrow2"></div>
    <li><a href="Generator.aspx">Generate </a></li>
     <li><a href="TLGenerator.aspx">Generate (TL) </a></li>
      <li><a href="PubKey.aspx">Instrument PKey</a></li>
    </ul></div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="About.aspx">About</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
     <div>
         <table style="width: 100%;">
             <tr>
                 <td class="auto-style2">
                     <table style="width: 100%;">
                         <tr>
                             <td class="auto-style8" colspan="4"><img class="auto-style1" src="Logo_screen.bmp" /></td>
                             <td class="auto-style9">&nbsp;</td>
                             <td class="auto-style9"></td>
                         </tr>
                         <tr>
                             <td class="auto-style7" colspan="5">
                                 <hr style="width: 667px" />
                             </td>
                             <td class="auto-style5" rowspan="4"></td>
                         </tr>
                         <tr>
                             <td class="auto-style7" colspan="2"></td>
                             <td class="auto-style4" colspan="2">
                                 &nbsp;</td>
                             <td rowspan="14">
                                 &nbsp;</td>
                         </tr>
                         <tr>
                             <td class="auto-style7" colspan="2"></td>
                             <td class="auto-style4" colspan="2">
                                 &nbsp;</td>
                         </tr>
                         <tr>
                             <td class="auto-style7" colspan="2"></td>
                             <td class="auto-style4" colspan="2">
                                 &nbsp;</td>
                         </tr>
                                                  <tr>
                             <td class="auto-style6" colspan="2" rowspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
                             <td class="auto-style3" colspan="2">
                                 &nbsp;</td>
                             <td rowspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
                         </tr>
                                                  <tr>
                             <td class="auto-style3" colspan="2">
                                 &nbsp;</td>
                         </tr>
                                                  <tr>
                             <td class="auto-style3" colspan="2">
                                 &nbsp;</td>
                         </tr>
                                                  <tr>
                             <td class="auto-style3" colspan="2">
                                 &nbsp;</td>
                         </tr>
                                                  <tr>
                             <td class="auto-style7" colspan="2"></td>
                             <td class="auto-style4" colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                             <td class="auto-style5"></td>
                         </tr>
                         </tr>
                                                  <tr>
                             <td class="auto-style6" colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                             <td class="auto-style3" colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                             <td>&nbsp;</td>
                         </tr>
                         <tr>
                             <td class="auto-style3">
                                 &nbsp;</td>
                             <td class="auto-style3" colspan="2">
                                 &nbsp;</td>
                             <td class="auto-style12">
                                 &nbsp;</td>
                             <td rowspan="6">&nbsp;</td>
                         </tr>
                         <tr>
                             <td class="auto-style3">
                                 &nbsp;</td>
                             <td class="auto-style3" colspan="2">
                                 &nbsp;</td>
                             <td class="auto-style12">
                                 &nbsp;</td>
                         </tr>
                         <tr>
                             <td class="auto-style7">
                                 </td>
                             <td class="auto-style7" colspan="2">
                                 </td>
                             <td class="auto-style13">
                                 </td>
                         </tr>
                         <tr>
                             <td class="auto-style3">
                                 &nbsp;</td>
                             <td class="auto-style3" colspan="2">
                                 &nbsp;</td>
                             <td class="auto-style12">
                                 &nbsp;</td>
                         </tr>
                         <tr>
                             <td class="auto-style3">
                                 &nbsp;</td>
                             <td class="auto-style3" colspan="2">
                                 &nbsp;</td>
                             <td class="auto-style12">
                                 &nbsp;</td>
                         </tr>
                         <tr>
                             <td class="auto-style3" colspan="5">
                                 <hr />
                             </td>
                         </tr>
                     </table>

                 <td>

                     &nbsp;</td>

             </table>

         </div>
        </div>
<div>

    &nbsp;</div>

    </form>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: by seeing the css its not clear what goes far right?

Comment: I would say your arrows are causing this: `right:-70%`, try positioning them absolute instead (whilst positioning the parent relative)

Comment: @ Kheema Pandey I've included a page and mentioned what got shifted right. @ Pete I checked what you mentioned but it made no difference after altering it. Thanks Guys! But I've not gotten a solution still

Comment: its because you are using `float:left` on `.nvbar`. you have to clear `float` property than the rest of the content will appear like you want.  I've added `<div style="clear:left;">` and its works now. check fiddle. http://jsbin.com/falexoke/1/edit

Comment: Works like a charm! (many thanks @ Kheema Pandey)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After seeing the code (posted here) not sure what's written in your `Layout.css` file. Here I can making only assumption that it might be happening because in class `.nvbar` have set a `float:left` property. By using `clearfix` property the layout will be fixed and not floated anymore on right side. See the **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/falexoke/1/edit)**.

Here is the clearfix CSS Method you need to add in your CSS file.

```
.nvbar:after{
  content: " ";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    overflow: hidden;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Hello Pandey... I ran into another hiccup. the dropdown on the menu works on both Firefox and Chrome but not on IE, :-|

Comment: My Friend I've checked in IE11 and drop down working fine. `clearfix Method ` have nothing to do with this dropdown.